# OtcFramework indexer component does not index some parts of the object tree with collections

Tags: otcconverter, otcframework

Issue Description:
When we have 2 copy-source commands with many collection types in the source object-paths where it is mostly similar for the first few collections, the source object values in the object path of the first copy command are not mapped / copied in the target object.

When I verify the generated code in debug mode with a debug point in the first line in the entry class, I observe the indexed collection tree has the indexed branch of only the second object-path.

When I interchange the sequence of the commands in the otcs file, then the other one is missing - ie. whichever is the first command in the otcs file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please create an issue on https://github.com/frank-a-otc/otcframework/issues.
This is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in v2.7.0 - pls pull from maven central.